# Find the tilt angle $\delta$ of a triangle (with interior angles $\alpha$, $\beta$) that is embedded in two stacked rectangles of height $d$ and $e$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

I have a triangle, whose interior angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are given. This triangle is embedded into two stacked rectangles, whose heights are given too. The height of the first rectangle is $d$ and the height of the second one is $e$.

Using the figure below, I am trying to describe the geometric situation:

[image]

How we can find a formula of the tilt angle $\delta$, which depends on the two angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and on the rectangles' heights $d$ and $e$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than a hint...$$AC=\frac{(e+d)}{\cos(\alpha+\delta)}$$ and $$BC=\frac{e}{\sin(\beta-\delta)}$$

Applying the Sine Rule in triangle $ABC$ gives $$\frac{(e+d)}{\cos(\alpha+\delta)\sin\beta}=\frac{e}{\sin(\beta-\delta)\sin\alpha}$$

Rearranging and expanding the compond angles leads to an expression for $\tan\delta$, namely, $$\tan\delta=\frac{\tan\beta}{\tan\alpha}.\left(\frac{(e+d)\tan\alpha-e}{e+d-e\tan\beta}\right)$$

Comment: Looks great. Using cotangens, your solution might even be greatly simplified.

Comment: Using cotangens I obtain then $\cot\delta=\frac{e}{d}(\cot\alpha+\cot\beta)+\cot\beta$

Answer (score 0):

The tilt angle depends also on the lengths of the sides of the triangle. If the triangle is too big it won't fit in the lines and if it's too small its vertices won't lie on the sides of the rectangles.

Let the length of side $AC$ be $b$. You can compute the tilt angle as

$$\arctan\frac{e+d}{\sqrt{b^2-(e+d)^2}}-\alpha$$

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I still think (and hope) that a solution exists not depending on the triangle's side. But your solution goes definitely into a very good direction.

Comment: David Quinn's solution is better than mine in that it doesn't _assume_ the length of the side but _computes_ it from the given data. However, it does depend on the length of the side.

Answer (score 0):

My approach was to imagine constructing the triangle on the three given lines. Suppose point $A$ is fixed, while $B$ moves freely on the middle line. The locus of point $C$ is then the blue line in my sketch, and $C$ must fall where this locus intersects the top line.

[image]

From $A$, use the latitude ($AL$) and departure ($LC$) to $C$.

$JK = d\tan{(\gamma-\frac{\pi}{2})} = -d\cot{\gamma}$

$MC = e\tan{(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha)} = e\cot{\alpha}$

$\tan{(\angle CAL)} = \frac{LC}{AL} = \frac{e\cot{\alpha} - d\cot{\gamma}}{d+e}$

$\delta = \frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha - \text{tan}^{-1}(\frac{e\cot{\alpha} - d\cot{\gamma}}{d+e})$

Comment: This is a nice solution too - thank you!